# Adding a char into string (or Chararray) c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, char

Let say I have a string  "ABCDEFGH"and I would like to add a char into this string such as (adding Z to the fourth column);

> ABC**Z**DEFGH

How can I do this efficiently instead of changing string into char, moving all chars to the new column, and adding the char later?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `string.Insert` method.

```
string test = "ABCDEFGH";
test = test.Insert(3, "Z");
```

Have a look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.insert) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just [Insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
  string source = "ABCDEFGH";
  char item = 'Z';

  string result = source.Insert(3, item.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
    string str = "ABCDEFGH";

    str = str.Insert(3, "Z");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use string.Insert:

```
var start = "ABCDEFGH";
var result = start.Insert(3, "Z");
```

Note that indexes are 0 based.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know the index you can do it like this

```
result = test.Insert(test.IndexOf("C"), "Z");
```